# How to prevent my text overflowing and make responsive div?

Tags: html, css

my text is overflowing see the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_9VvP54CAJJSvtsArZiTMMfMzACDS11/view?usp=sharing

here is css:

```
.card_main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 900px;
  background: #ffffff;

  width: 100%;
}
.blog_content__text {
  width: 95%;
  height: 320px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid lightgray;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.blog_heading {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
}
    .blog_details {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

**my html**

```
 <div className="card_main">
     <div className="blog_content__text">
     <h1 className="blog_heading">{data.blog_title}</h1>
     <p className="blog_details">{data.blog_body}</p>
      </div>
<div/>
```

how to prevent overflowing my text and make the div responsive. I am not an CSS expert. I just start learning css

Comment: make a snippet with your source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using fixed height for a div, you also need to say how the scroll should work. In this case using **overflow-y:auto** makes sense. You may prefer **overflow-y:hidden** or always show scrollbars **overflow-y:scroll;**

If there is no serious limitation in terms of graphics, **do not specify the height for a Div** to make its height responsive to the content.

```
.blog_content__text {
  width: 95%;
  height: 320px;

  overflow-y:auto;

  border-bottom: 1.5px solid lightgray;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Ali Sheikhpour now text not overflowing but I need to scrolling to see more text.  I want full text will be showing inside my container https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_9VvP54CAJJSvtsArZiTMMfMzACDS11/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't want scrolling to see more text.

Answer (score 0):

remove the  height: 320px;
if you must, use it as min-height: 320px;

Answer (score 0):

try setting a margin-bottom css attribute to the div that contains the text, the value of the margin should equal the height of that white footer that is hiding the text on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the following property if you really want to set the height:

```
height: min-content;
```